# How to Benchmark VS2010 Installations

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm doing a VS2010 Installation on a VM Machine and 1 on a Physical PC.

VM Spec: 
Xeon CPU 3.33 GHZ (duo core)
Windows 7 64 Bit
4 GB of Ram

Physical PC: 
Duo Core CPU (speed unknown at this time)
Windows 7 64 Bit
6 GB of Ram

My Question is, what is the best way to run some sort of benchmark test with VS2010 to determine what has the best performance?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd just get a machine with a re-inforced case because once VS2010 starts throwing the AVs at you you'll want to kick it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real life benchmarking is easy to do: Take a project you are working on (or any project similar to it in structure), and measure a time of a full rebuild.

If the project does not take long enough for the results to be representative or interesting, then I say why would you care about the performance at all?

As project by different teams differ a lot (some use more templates, some more of complex and difficult to optimize expressions, some lots of small files, some lots of libraries ..., some C++, some C#), I doubt there could exist a "universal benchmark project" useful enough to you. Taking the real project your developers are working on is the most representative you can do.

If you want just to have some rough "order of magnitude" comparison, you can simply download some large enough open source project in the same language as you do. E.g. for C you might want to try something like [OGG library source](http://www.xiph.org/downloads/) or [LibPNG source](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngcode.html).

Comment: The benchmarking will help me decided on how to build the other Machines for my Dev. Team.

Comment: I did intend to do that. Just thought I'd reach out to the community to see if anyone else had some other alternatives.  For instance would there be a complex enough project on Codeplex that I could download and build ?

Comment: Complex enough is not enough - the project would have also to be similar in structure and constructs used to your projects, otherwise it can easily be not representative.